# Different Screen Shot Resolution in Different Browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing a problem related to my Project of GUI comparison...

It takes Screen Shots of given URL in different Browsers, but these Screen Shots are having different Resolution for different Browser.

So, my problem is that now what to do for getting the Same Resolution of all the screen shots in different Browsers.???

If any solution is there then kindly tell me.

Detail:

- Resolutions With:

  - Mozilla Firefox:- 1345*627
  - Google Chrome:- 1345*659
  - Internet Explorer:- 1345*679
- Tools used:

  - Selenium Web Driver.
  - Java

Comment: Is the view set to 100% in all the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try maximising the driver window

Example with Junit & webdriver:

```
public class Untitled {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }

  @Test
  public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
driver.get(baseUrl);

  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }`
```

Comment: try to set a specific size using the  driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));